# App Script HtmlService use with font like Google Web Fonts?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-caja

I trying to do one (!) page with the app script HtmlService but want to have specific web fonts.

I added the CSS code for the web fonts, and integrated it with my CSS. It's not working.

I suspect *Google Caja* (HtmlService is going through the Caja filter) not being able to work with web fonts. Would you know if I am doing something wrong with HtmlService, or if there is any other way to have web fonts through the filtering of Caja?

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fugaz+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The stylesheet you refer to](http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fugaz+One) uses `@font-face` to load a font. Caja does not currently support `@font-face`, since it refers to external content (the font data) which [Caja does not implement sanitization of and has not reviewed the risks of allowing through unchanged](http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/source/browse/trunk/src/com/google/caja/plugin/CssValidator.java?spec=svn5085&r=5079#416).

If you would like to have `@font-face` support, please file an issue on [Caja's public issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/issues/list) requesting it.

(I am a developer on the Caja team.)

Comment: Kevin, thanks, that answer my question. Though I am wondering if you would know any other method bypassing @font-face and that would work with Caja?

Comment: I created the [issue 1559](http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/issues/detail?id=1559) on the Caja issue tracker. Anybody interested in this issue should _star_ it. Thanks. Also anybody tried [Cufòn](https://github.com/sorccu/cufon/wiki) with Caja?